# detach call is not working as per expectation

Tags: multithreading, c++11, detach

Need help why below codes are working differently.
In this code thread is not printing anything after main exit:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void Run()
{

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        cout<<"=== "<< "start_point" <<" ==="<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    std::thread th(Run);

    th.detach();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    cout<<"==== Ending main ==="<<std::endl;
}
```

But Here proper messages getting printed after thread exit:

```
void independentThread() 
{
    std::cout << "Starting concurrent thread.\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    std::cout << "Exiting concurrent thread.\n";
}

void threadCaller() 
{
    std::cout << "Starting thread caller.\n";
    std::thread t(independentThread);
    t.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Exiting thread caller.\n";
}

int main() 
{
    threadCaller();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

Should be something very small and I am missing it.
Compiler information:
     g++ / Mac / c++11

tried to search on google but not luck.

Edit-1:
Result for first program:

```
=== start_point ===
=== start_point ===
==== Ending main ===
```

Result for 2nd Program:

```
Starting thread caller.
Starting concurrent thread.
Exiting thread caller.
Exiting concurrent thread.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks like it is executing correctly to me.

Normally when `thread`'s destructor runs, it will wait for the thread to finish before exiting. However, when you call `detach()`, you are circumventing this behavior - the current method won't wait for the thread to finish.

Since the thread will run for (approximately) 6 seconds, the sleep in `main()` doesn't wait long enough for the threat to finish, so it will exit before the thread has finished. Depending on the environment, it's possible that exiting `main()` will also exit the program - meaning the thread doesn't ever get a chance to print all of its messages before the program exits.

If you want to explicitly wait for the thread to finish before continuing execution, you should call [`thread::join()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Then why is working for 2nd program even after main's exit.

Comment: I know we can use Join, but I just want to know why they are behaving differently. Am I missing something from basic?!!!

Comment: got it. Thanks for your response. It system environment which is blocking execution after main's exit. Same this will happen for 2nd program if I increase the sleep time for thread. Once again Thank you Andy.